# how to pipe functions, when a promise in the promise in the middle checks authorization?

Tags: functional-programming, ecmascript-6, promise, composition

i'm trying to compose some functions together:

```
compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)));
```

`checkAuthorization` returns a promise that check if a user is authorized.
`buildParams` receives `someRequestData`, and pipes the result to `searchItem`.

```
    checkAuthorization()
      .then(() => {
            compose(
                searchItem,
                buildParams
            )(someRequestData)
    }, (e) => {
       handleError(e)
    })
```

I think it's OK, but I wish to have a more elegant look for readability, something like:

```
    compose(
      searchItem,
      checkAuthorization
      buildParams
    )(someRequestData)
```

so what will happen is: 
1) build params
2) checkAuth
3) search item

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible, since `checkAuthorisation` does not receive and pass through the params. And even if you would rewrite it to do that, it still would be weird and a reader would assume that you're building the params whose authorisation should be checked. So don't do that - you have a non-linear flow, and trying to force it into some linear composition is no good.

Btw, I would recommend to avoid `compose` when you're calling the function immediately anyway:

```
checkAuthorization().then(() =>
  searchItem(buildParams(someRequestData))
, e =>
   handleError(e)
);
```

or maybe

```
checkAuthorization().then( compose(searchItem, buildParams, ()=>someRequestData)
                         , handleError ); //                ^^^^ "const"
```

Comment: @Bergi, please look at my answer. What's your opinion? And how can I also track possible `reject` states there if you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a composer to handle both sync functions and Promises. Looks like it works correctly maintaining the order:

```js
// Async pipe try. Pass functions left to right
const pipePromises = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve(x));
  
// functions for the test
const me = x => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(x), 10)
})

const double = x => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(x * 2), 30)
})

const inc = x => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(x + 1), 400)
})

const log = x => { console.log('log: ', x); return x }

const syncTriple = x => x * 3; // sync function

// let's call our chain
pipePromises( 
  me, log, // 3
  double, log, // 6
  syncTriple, log, // 18 -- SYNC
  inc, log, // 19
  double, log, // 38
  inc, log, // 39
  syncTriple, log, // 117 -- SYNC
  inc, log // 118
)(3) // 3
```

Comment: I would say that `log` should be sync as well. And yes, while you can build such a function (and [others have done it as well](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#composeP)), I don't think it applies to the question.

Comment: Never distinguish promises from non-promises like you did (that horrible `.constructor.name` check doesn't even work on most implementations). You should use `Promise.resolve(v)` and always treat it as asynchronous. For a composition function, you know that `v` is a promise is anyway. So `function composePromises(...fns) { return v => fns.reduceRight((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve(v)); }`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi , this is much better.

Comment: I know I can also use promises composition with Ramda.js, but I don't like the idea of turning sync function async in order to compose them. but that's an interesting code!

Answer (score 1):

I just made an [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mix) to handle elegant `Promise` composition.
It's still in early stage, but you're welcome to check out the code and change it as it fits your needs and standards.

Basically it offers two methods which might meet your needs:

#### Combine

With `Promise.combine({...})` you can combine several Promises by providing an object with a series of functions returning Promises and accepting the result of previous ones as input like this:

```
Promise.combine({
  item: () => searchItem,
  auth: ({item}) => checkAuth,
  params: ({item, auth}) => buildParams
}).then(({item, auth, params}) => {
  // here you can do what you need
})
```

#### Reduce

With `Promise.reduce([...])` you can chain Promises in an array of functions returning Promises and accepting as input the output of the previously executed Promise:

```
Promise.reduce([
  () => searchItem,
  (item) => checkAuth,
  (auth) => buildParams
]).then((params) => {
  // here you can do what you need
})
```

Notice in this case you won't have access to `item` in the `.then()` function, but you could always compose the result of the `checkAuth` Promise in order to pass the `item` downstream as well:

```
Promise.reduce([
  () => searchItem,
  (item) => checkAuth.then((auth) => {
      return {auth, item}
  }),
  ({auth, item}) => buildParams.then((params) => {
      return {params, item}
  }),
]).then(({params, item}) => {
  // here you can do what you need
})
```

#### Input

You can also add some input data from the request like this:

```
Promise.reduce([
  (requestData) => searchItem,
  (item) => checkAuth,
  (auth) => buildParams
], requestData).then((params) => {
  // here you can do what you need
})
```

See I passed the `requestData` as second parameter of `Promise.reduce([...], requestData)` and it gets passed as parameter to the first function.

[Here you can see the functions code.](https://github.com/Onheiron/promise-mix/blob/master/promise-mix.js)
Hope this helps.