# ES6 Dyanmic Promise Chaining from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

**Scenario**

I have an array of URLs that I need to download, however each must also be supplied with a unique transaction ID that must be requested from the server and only increments when a request is successful.

**Problem**

As I loop through the array I need to wait for both the request for the transaction ID and the request for the file to complete before starting the next iteration of the loop but the number of files is not fixed so need to dynamically build a chain of promises.

**Pseudocode**

Below is some pseudocode, getFiles() is the problem because all the requests get the same transaction Id as they don't wait for the previous request to finish.

```
function getTransationId(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
        let id = getNextTransactionId();
        if(id!=error){
            resolve(id);
        }else{
            reject(error);
        }
    })
}

function getFile(url, transactionId){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        http.request(url+transactionId, function(err,response){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }else{
                resolve(response);
            }
        });
    });
}

function getFilesFromArray(urlArray){
    for(let url of urlArray){
        getTransactionId().then(resolve=>getFile(url,resolve),reject=>console.error(reject));
    }
}
```

**Question**

How do I chain chain promises together dynamically?

**Answer**

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DystarPlays/ccavr4x6/4/) of [Ovidiu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5379496/ovidiu-dolha) answer

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371402/7636961

Comment: If `getNextTransactionId` returns the `id`, why do you need to wrap it in a Promise? Your example then compares to an undefined `error`. It's hard to tell what is causing the problem without knowing what `getNextTransactionId` is returning.

Comment: `getTransactionId()` is a call to the server so we need to wait for the response before continuing otherwise the Id will be `undefined`.  In terms of the error I've over simplified the process to illustrate the problem hence calling is pseudocode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A functional approach is to use `reduce` to iterate and return a final promise chained up from each sub-promise. It also helps building the results e.g. in an array:

```
function getFilesFromArray(urlArray){
    const filesPromise = urlArray.reduce((curPromise, url) => {
        return curPromise
           .then(curFiles => {
                return getTransactionId()
                    .then(id => getFile(url, id))
                    .then(newFile => [...curFiles, newFile]);
           });
    }, Promise.resolve([]));

    filesPromise.then(files => {
         console.log(files);
    }
}
```

This effectively builds a promise chain that:

- starts with a static `Promise` with a value `[]` representing the initial set of files: `Promise.resolve([])`
- on each iteration, returns a promise that waits for the `curPromise` in the chain and then
- performs `getTransactionId` and uses the id to `getFile`
- once the file will be retrieved it will return an array containing the `curFiles` set in the the `curPromise` (previous values) and concatenates the newFile into it
- the end result will be a single promise with all files collected

Comment: Really nice answer, `[...a, b]` is new syntax to me and it's beautiful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines

```
function getAllFiles(i, results, urlArray) {
    if(i == urlArray.length) return;

    getTransationId().then(id => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            http.request(urlArray[i] + id, (err, response) => {
                if(err){
                    reject();
                }else{
                    results.push(response);
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    }).then(() => {
        getAllFiles(i + 1, results, urlArray);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using async/await.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
async function getFilesFromArray(urlArray) {
      for(let url of urlArray){
         //wrap this in a try/catch block if you want to continue with execution 
         //if you receive an error from one of the functions
         const transactionId =await getTransactionId()
         const file = await getFile(url,transactionId)
}
}
```

Comment: ES6 aka ES2015 does **NOT** include async/await. this feature is only officially ready in ES2017. nodejs officially supports this from version 7.6

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify logic if you run it via synchronous executor [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs). Nsynjs will pause when some function evaluates to promise, and then assigns the result to `data` property. The code will transform like this:

```
function getFilesFromArray(urlArray){
    for(var i = 0; i<urlArray.length; i++) {
        var trId = getTransactionId().data;
        // trId is ready here
        var fileContent = getFile(urlArray[i],trId).data;
        // file data is ready here
        console.log('fileContent=',fileContent);
    };
};

nsynjs.run(getFilesFromArray,{},urls,function(){
    console.log('getFilesFromArray is done');
});
```

getFilesFromArray can be further simplified to:

```
function getFilesFromArray(urlArray){
    for(var i = 0; i<urlArray.length; i++) {
        var fileContent = getFile(urlArray[i],getTransactionId().data).data;
        console.log('fileContent=',fileContent);
    };
};
```